# Plotting 3D points with Python Matploltlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d

I want to create a small simulation, and I think I know how, but in order to actually see what happens I need to visualize it.

I started with a 5x5x5 array, which I want to fill up with values.

```
data = numpy.zeros(shape=(5,5,5))
data[:,:,0]=4
data[:,:,1]=3
data[:,:,2]=2
data[:,:,3]=1
data[:,:,4]=0
```

This should create a cube which has a gradient in the upward direction (if the third axis is z).

Now, how can I plot this? I dont want a surface plot, or wireframe. Just Points on each coordinate, and maybe colorcoded or transperency by value.

As a test I tried plotting all coordinates using

```
ax.scatter(numpy.arange(5),numpy.arange(5),numpy.arange(5))
```

but this will only plot a line consisting of 5 dots.

So... how can I get the 125 dots, that I want to create?

Thx.

Comment: I just found meshgrid... now scatter will plot all 125 points, so I would no only have to somehow a assign a value to each of those points, lets say from 0 to 100 in z direction .... how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can encode the value in color like this:

```
x = np.arange(5)
X, Y, Z = np.meshgrid(x,x,x)

v = np.arange(125)
ax.scatter(X,Y,Z, c=v)
```

See [here](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#scatter-plots) for the documention.